# android: getBackground.setAlpha() changes alpha of all activities with same background-image

Tags: java, android, background-image, alpha

For example, if I add the following line to my 2nd activity, the alpha value for the background image will also change in my 1st activity, because I used the same image.

```
findViewById(R.id.main).getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

But I don't want that. The two activities should have different alpha values, but still have the same drawable as background image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: .getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(x); try this

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [`mutate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()) to create a separate instance before setting the alpha. As per the documentation:

> A mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other drawable. This is especially useful when you need to modify properties of drawables loaded from resources. **By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state;** if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you